# Sql query to show minutes as hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql query which return no of minutes and query is

```
select 
 PSProjectId,CodePattern,NCR,sum(totaltime) as totaltime --totaltime is in minutes
  from ct2
group by PSProjectId,CodePattern,NCR
```

and output is

```
PSProjectId CodePattern NCR totaltime
0000108676  001         blank   NULL
0000109530  520297      blank   24
0000109530  520297S     blank   12
0000109530  520297SREW  blank   9
0000131756  3UA1PSREW   blank   NULL
```

But i want to show total time in hours

eg : 24 should be .4,12 should display as .2 etc

Comment: you're gonna have to do some math

Comment: we are coders, not math teachers :p

Comment: I know but but could you show me some examples.. i mean tried /60 and % 60 but  i am not getting desired result. I can show as HH:MM but i don not need this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select 
 PSProjectId,CodePattern,NCR,sum(totaltime)/60.0 as totaltime --totaltime is in minutes
  from ct2
group by PSProjectId,CodePattern,NCR
```

Comment: by dividing 60 it won't show value which is below 60

Comment: @Spenzo Dividing with an integer gives you an integer result. Divide by `60.0` instead.